# Can't change the text on an object?

Tags: c#, label

I can't seem to change the text on any object - I've tried both labels and buttons so far. Why doesn't this work?

```
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 60; i >=1; i--){
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            i -= 1;
            label1.Text = i.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Making the UI thread sleep is a bad idea.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I guess the OP is just trying to simulate a processor intensive task by using `Thread.Sleep(1000)`

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because you are using a busy loop to update the text.

This code runs in the main thread, so it's busy setting the `Text` property for a whole minute, and can't update the user interface.

You would use a timer to update the text, so that the main thread regains the control in between changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the Thread.Sleep() command to see if the label is updated.  You may find that the UI thread exits the function even though you requested it to sleep.

What you can do is use a Timer control, and set the interval to 1000 (1 second). Then you can set the label1.Text to a counter or static field value (or hidden field).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you stay in the `Button1Click` the UI thread seams to be sleeping. Delete the `Thread.Sleep` and you will see that the text is shown in the labels.

Answer (score 0):

put [`Application.DoEvents();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) in your code after last line, then it will work for sure.

```
       for (int i = 60; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            i -= 1;
            label1.Text = i.ToString();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

Comment: Calling `DoEvents` only once a second would still make the application seem quite unresponsive. Also note that it only works if there is only one task like this, if you start another while the first is running, the first will pause while the second runs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to learn [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx).

You need to create a thread and use Invoke delegate.

```
Thread th = new Thread(test);
th.Start();  //start the thread
```

This method will update the lable.text

```
void test()
{
    for (int i = 60; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            label1.Invoke(new Action(()  => {
                label1.Text = i.ToString();

            }));

        }
    }
}
```